# SQL error on pagination

Tags: mysql, cakephp, pagination

Hey guys we have a perfectly working web page (index_admin) of the Relationships controller, but after adding pagination its all crashing.

Coming up with:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Relationship.sender_id' in 'where clause'
```

Customers and businesses build 'relationships' so they can exchange invoices over our website. Here is the DB schema:

id, sender_id, receiver_id, active, requested, expiry_date

Sender_id and receiver_id are both foreign keys to the Account Table. So in other words tells the db which accounts are linked to each other.

Relationship model 'BELONGSTO' 'RECEIVER AND SENDER ACCOUNT MODELS':

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'ReceiverAccount' =>array(
            'className' => 'Account',
            'foreignKey' =>'receiver_id',
            'associationForeignKey'  => 'accounts_id',
            ),
        'SenderAccount' =>array(
            'className' => 'Account',
            'foreignKey' =>'sender_id',
            'associationForeignKey'  => 'accounts_id',)
            );
```

Index_admin:

```
public function index_admin(){
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Relationships');
        $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
        $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.png');   
        $this->layout='home_layout';

        //retrieve Account Id of current User       
        $accountid=$this->Auth->user('account_id');

        //Conditions
        $conditions=array(
        "OR"=> array(
            'Relationship.sender_id' => $accountid,
            'Relationship.receiver_id' => $accountid)
        );



        //Find all Invoices where receiver_id = accountid
        $relationships=$this->Relationship->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => $conditions));

        debug($conditions);

        $compName = $this->Account->field('account_name', array('id' => 'Relationship.id'));

        $this->paginate = array(
        'limit' => 10,
        'conditions'=> $conditions
        );

        $this->set('accountid', $accountid); 
        $this->set('relationship', $this->paginate());  

        $this->set('compName', $compName);  
    }
```

Index_admin view (partial):

```
<table id="data">
                <tr>
                        <td colspan=7 align='right'>
                        <?php 
                        echo $this->Paginator->prev('<' . __('previous'), array(), null, array('class'=>'prev disabled'));  
                        echo '&nbsp;';
                        echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('seperator'=>'')); 
                        echo '&nbsp;';
                        echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . '>', array(), null, array('class'=>'next disabled'));
                        ?>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id'); ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('sender_id'); ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('receiver_id'); ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('expiry_date'); ?></th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>

        <?php foreach($relationship as $relationships):?>

        <?php

        if($relationships['Relationship']['requested']==1)
        {
            $status = 'Requested';
            $bgcol = '#F8FAC0';
        }
        else if($relationships['Relationship']['active']==1)
        {
            $status = 'Active';
            $bgcol = '#CFDAE8';
        }
        else if($relationships['Relationship']['active']==0)
        {
            $status = 'Expired';
            $bgcol = '#FAB9B9';
        }       

        if($relationships['Relationship']['active']==0 && $relationships['Relationship']['requested']==0)
        {
            $action = 'Reactivate';
        }
        else
        {
            $action = 'Edit Expiry';
        }

        if($relationships['Relationship']['sender_id']==$accountid)
        {
            $start = '<font color="#191970">';
            $end = '</font>';
        }
        else
        {
            $start = NULL;
            $end = NULL;
        }

        if($relationships['Relationship']['receiver_id']==$accountid)
        {
            $startr = '<font color="#191970">';
            $endr = '</font>';
        }
        else
        {
            $startr = NULL;
            $endr = NULL;
        }


        if($relationships['Relationship']['sender_id']==$accountid)
        {
            $acctname = $relationships['ReceiverAccount']['account_name'];
        }
        else if($relationships['Relationship']['receiver_id']==$accountid)
        {
            $acctname = $relationships['SenderAccount']['account_name'];
        }

?>

                    <tr>
                        <td align='center'><?php echo $relationships['Relationship']['id']; ?></td>
                        <td align='center'><?php echo $start?><?php echo $relationships['SenderAccount']['account_name']; ?><?php echo $end ?></td>
                        <td align='center'><?php echo $startr?><?php echo $relationships['ReceiverAccount']['account_name']; ?><?php echo $endr ?></td>
                        <td align='center'><?php echo date('d.m.Y', strtotime($relationships['Relationship']['expiry_date'])); ?></td>
                        <td align='center' bgcolor='<?php echo $bgcol ?>'><?php echo $status ?></td>
                        <td align='center'> 
                        <?php echo $this->Form->Html->link('Delete', array('controller' => 'Relationships','action'=>'delete',$relationships['Relationship']['id']), NULL, 'Are you sure you want to delete '. $acctname);
                         ?> | <?php echo $action ?> </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

            <tr>
                        <td colspan=7 align='right'>
                        <?php 
                        echo $this->Paginator->prev('<' . __('previous'), array(), null, array('class'=>'prev disabled'));  
                        echo '&nbsp;';
                        echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('seperator'=>'')); 
                        echo '&nbsp;';
                        echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . '>', array(), null, array('class'=>'next disabled'));
                        ?>
                        </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

Like I said it was all working before hand, now it isn't, but I can't see why.

Comment: Is there a column named Relationship.sender_id?

Comment: Yes obviously. As I said, it was all working. If you read above in the Relationship table there is sender_id....

Comment: What returns  `debug($conditions);` ?

Comment: You say it works before adding pagination. Does that means it works before using `$this->paginate` so `$this->find('all', compact('conditions'))` works? Also, please post the CakePHP version you're using.

Comment: Find the SQL the failing `paginate()` generates and sanity-check it. Run it against your database manually and see what happens.

Comment: One thing I see, although I doubt it's causing the issue, is that in your model you have an index of 'associationForeignKey'  => 'accounts_id', but you show these as "belongs_to" associations and "associationForeignKey" is only a valid index for HABTM relationships.

Answer (score 1):

It is always wise to set the debug mode on to see all possible errors in detail. You've just shared the sql error part from which it is clear that **the intended table doesn't have the "sender_id" field**. I'm assuming you've debug mode on. So first have a look at the generated query. Then you'll find which table the query is trying to dig in.

If your query is referencing the correct table, you can try this:

```
public function index_admin(){
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Relationships');
        $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
        $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.png');   
        $this->layout='home_layout';

        //retrieve Account Id of current User       
        $accountid=$this->Auth->user('account_id');

        //Conditions
        $conditions=array(
        "OR"=> array(
            'Relationship.sender_id' => $accountid,
            'Relationship.receiver_id' => $accountid)
        );
        App::import('Model', 'Relationship');
        $objRelationship = new Relationship();
        $this->paginate = array( "conditions" => $conditions, 'limit' => 10 );
        $relationships = $this->paginate( $objRelationship );

        $compName = $this->Account->field('account_name', array('id' => 'Relationship.id'));

        $this->set('accountid', $accountid); 
        $this->set('relationship', $this->paginate());  
        $this->set('compName', $compName);
}
```