# Pagination and database error cakephp

Tags: database, cakephp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CakePHP website crashing after pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469128/cakephp-website-crashing-after-pagination)

I had a page that worked but then decided to add in the functionality of pagination - it worked on that page and now trying to copy it over to another page I am now getting pdo database errors. saying that the variable `Relationship.sender_id` doesn't exist.

I have a `relationship` table which contains - `id, sender_id, receiver_id, expiry_date,active`

here is the code in the function

```
    public function index_admin(){

    //retrieve Account Id of current User       
    $accountid=$this->Auth->user('account_id');

    //Conditions
    $conditions=array(
    "OR"=> array(
        'Relationship.sender_id' => $accountid,
        'Relationship.receiver_id' => $accountid)
    );

    //Find all Relationships where receiver_id = accountid
    $relationships=$this->Relationship->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => $conditions));


    $compName = $this->Account->field('account_name', array('id' => 'Relationship.id'));

    $this->paginate = array(
    'limit' => 10,
    'conditions'=> $conditions);

    $this->set('accountid', $accountid); 
    $this->set('relationship', $this->paginate());  

    $this->set('compName', $compName);  
}
```

this has really thrown me, any help would be appreciated.

this is the sql query the code creates

```
SELECT `Relationship`.`id`, `Relationship`.`sender_id`, `Relationship`.`receiver_id`,
 `Relationship`.`active`, `Relationship`.`requested`, `Relationship`.`expiry_date`, 
`ReceiverAccount`.`id`, `ReceiverAccount`.`street`, `ReceiverAccount`.`city`, 
`ReceiverAccount`.`postcode`, `ReceiverAccount`.`state`, `ReceiverAccount`.`country`,
 `ReceiverAccount`.`active`, `ReceiverAccount`.`account_name`, `ReceiverAccount`.`abn`,
 `SenderAccount`.`id`, `SenderAccount`.`street`, `SenderAccount`.`city`, 
`SenderAccount`.`postcode`, `SenderAccount`.`state`, `SenderAccount`.`country`, 
`SenderAccount`.`active`, `SenderAccount`.`account_name`, `SenderAccount`.`abn` 
FROM 
`pra`.`relationships` AS `Relationship` LEFT JOIN 
`pra`.`accounts` AS `ReceiverAccount` ON (
`Relationship`.`receiver_id` = `ReceiverAccount`.`id`) LEFT JOIN 
`pra`.`accounts` AS `SenderAccount` ON (
`Relationship`.`sender_id` = `SenderAccount`.`id`) WHERE (
(`Relationship`.`sender_id` = 2) OR (`Relationship`.`receiver_id` = 2))
```

when I debug $relationships after commenting out the pagination, I get the following output

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Relationship' => array(
            'id' => '5',
            'sender_id' => '3',
            'receiver_id' => '2',
            'active' => false,
            'requested' => false,
            'expiry_date' => '2012-05-09'
        ),
        'ReceiverAccount' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'street' => '50 Simmington Circuit',
            'city' => 'Greenvale',
            'postcode' => '3059',
            'state' => 'VIC',
            'country' => 'Australia',
            'active' => true,
            'account_name' => 'Kialla Transport (Operations) Pty Ltd',
            'abn' => '2147483647'
        ),
        'SenderAccount' => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'street' => '31 Simmington Circuit',
            'city' => 'Greenvale',
            'postcode' => '3059',
            'state' => 'VIC',
            'country' => 'Australia',
            'active' => true,
            'account_name' => 'MGD Kialla Pty Ltd',
            'abn' => '2147483647'
        )
    ),
```

Comment: what returns debug($relationships); ? (comment paginate for a moment and see)

Comment: This is part of a group assignment, it is possible that it's duplicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove lines:

```
$this->paginate = array(
'limit' => 10,
'conditions'=> $conditions);
```

at the top of the Relationship controller add variable:

```
public $paginate = array(
  'Relationship' = > array(
    'limit' => 10)
   )
);
```

then try:

```
$this->set('relationship', $this->paginate('Relationship', $conditions));
```

this hould solve the problem...

Comment: no luck, still throws the error

Comment: does it work if you simplyfi the condition... like `$conditions=array('Relationship.sender_id' => $accountid);` ?

Comment: no, same error comes up when I simplify it too either sender_id or relationship_id

Comment: I updated the question with debug printout

Comment: yeah, worked cheers mate. odd that it worked with one controller the way I had it and now works differently in another controller.

Comment: there was some kind of diffrence for shure... but this (abowe) way should always work